# How much rust is okay on a used Nissan Rogue 2015?

Tags: nissan, rust, used, rogue

[How much rust is okay on a used Nissan Rogue 2015?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G9E9.jpg)

Please see pics of undercarriage and brake rust on a car from NJ.

Run 35000 miles. Is this a major issue/deal-breaker?

There seems to be no rust on the body anywhere else. Not sure if this is still a good buy?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayPsk.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!  In its current form, this question isn't on topic because any answers to this question are going to be opinion-based.  We need questions to have a definite objective answer.  If you can rework this to be [on topic](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), go ahead and [edit](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/61603/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0):

While answers might be opinion-based, none of that looks like a "deal-breaker" to me.

The exhaust pipe might be questionable, but that's a non-critical item and a cheap fix if needed.

Most of the rust is on fastener exterior surfaces and bare metal spots.  From what little I can see, there seems to be almost no serious rust on any suspension components or anything structural in the unibody.

I can't attest on whether or not it's a "good buy", but rust wouldn't be my concern.

You should take it to a competent mechanic for a complete diagnostic check.  You may even be able to negotiate the price of this with the seller if it checks out, and you buy it.  Otherwise, you'll have to eat the cost, but the $75-$100 diagnostic fee will be some of the best insurance you can buy.  Some shops will do it for free (or credit the cost), if you agree to whatever minor repairs it might need when you buy it... maybe brake pads or spark plugs or two new tires, etc.

If the seller won't let it be checked out by an agreed upon mechanic (not my Uncle Jim that works on cars sometimes), then I would RUN away.